# Issues with Caesar cipher

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

I have got a problem with decrypting a Caesar cipher in C#. We have to do it *manually*, encrypt and decrypt. I want it to write *all possibilities* shifting one by one (then it is easy to see the right decryption, because other `25` possibilities are nonsense). The problem is that it writes only one possibility, not `26`. I tried everything. Do you have any idea where is the problem?

```
string text = "Z programovani{}{}{}";
text = text.ToUpper();
string output = "";
int shift = 3;

foreach (char a in text)
{
    int x = (int)a;
    if (x >= 65 && x <= 90)
    {
        x += shift;
    }
    if (x == 32)
    {
        x -= shift;
    }
    if (x >90)
    {
        x = x - 26;
    }

    output += (char)x;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);

int i = 0;
do
{
    string decoded = "";

    foreach (char a in output)
    {
        int x = (int)a;
        if (x >= 65 && x <= 90)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        if (x > 90)
        {
            x = x + 26;
        }

        decoded += (char)x;
    }
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine(decoded);
} while (i < 27);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the description of the problem.  What do you mean by "we have to do it manually"?

Comment: Just that we shift it manually, for example to 3 or -5 etc.

Answer (score 3):

Let's *extract a method* (do not cram everyting into single `Main`; *decompose* your solution, make it simpler, easier to read and maintain):

```
private static string Caesar(string value, int shift) {
  if (null == value)
    return null;

  // Normalization: if we have shift out of [0..25] range, e.g. -3 or 125
  shift = ((shift % 26) + 26) % 26;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  foreach (var c in value) 
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
      sb.Append((char)((c - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a')); 
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      sb.Append((char)((c - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A'));
    else
      sb.Append(c);

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you can easily use it:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string text = "Z programovani{}{}{}";

// Let's use Linq; loop 
// for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) Console.WriteLine($"{i,2}: {Caesar(text, i)}");  
// is an alternative
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(0, 26)
  .Select(i => $"{i,2}: {Caesar(text, i)}"));

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 0: Z programovani{}{}{}
 1: A qsphsbnpwboj{}{}{}
 2: B rtqitcoqxcpk{}{}{}
 3: C surjudprydql{}{}{}
 4: D tvskveqszerm{}{}{}
 5: E uwtlwfrtafsn{}{}{}
 6: F vxumxgsubgto{}{}{}
 7: G wyvnyhtvchup{}{}{}
 8: H xzwoziuwdivq{}{}{}
 9: I yaxpajvxejwr{}{}{}
10: J zbyqbkwyfkxs{}{}{}
11: K aczrclxzglyt{}{}{}
12: L bdasdmyahmzu{}{}{}
13: M cebtenzbinav{}{}{}
14: N dfcufoacjobw{}{}{}
15: O egdvgpbdkpcx{}{}{}
16: P fhewhqcelqdy{}{}{}
17: Q gifxirdfmrez{}{}{}
18: R hjgyjsegnsfa{}{}{}
19: S ikhzktfhotgb{}{}{}
20: T jlialugipuhc{}{}{}
21: U kmjbmvhjqvid{}{}{}
22: V lnkcnwikrwje{}{}{}
23: W moldoxjlsxkf{}{}{}
24: X npmepykmtylg{}{}{}
25: Y oqnfqzlnuzmh{}{}{}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that is what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

When playing with Cypher, a common question is "How to handle Letter that are not in our base Alphabet?".
The idea of an alphabet is one simple way to handle `[az AZ 09]` range and even add punctuation. Here the minial version.

```
static string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Then with simple function to divide into simple task:
- ShiftChar, Shit the char in our alphabet with the cypher key.
- Cypher, cypher a word.
- AllCypher, compute all cypher.

```
char ShiftChar(char letter, int key, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    => alphabet[EuclydianModulo(AlphabetIndex(letter, comparisonType) + key, alphabet.Length)];

int EuclydianModulo(int dividend, int divisor) //As % computes the remainder, not the modulo
    => ((dividend % divisor) + divisor) % divisor;

string Cypher(string word, int key, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    => new string(  // To Return a string from char Array
        word.Select(x => // If letter is not in the alphabet, Don't crypt that letter. 
             alphabet.IndexOf(word, comparisonType) >= 0 ? ShiftChar(x, key, comparisonType) : x
            ).ToArray()
       );

List<string> AllCypher(string word, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, alphabet.Length)
                  // If word is null, string.Empty.
                 .Select(key => Cypher(word??string.Empty, key, comparisonType))
                 .ToList();

internal void TestCase_SO_52991034()
{
    var inputTest = new[] { "cake", "Ufhp rd gtc bnym knaj itejs qnvztw ozlx.", null };
    var result = inputTest.Select(x => new { word = x, cypher = AllCypher(x) });


    var ignoreCase = AllCypher("ABC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    var caseSentitiv =  AllCypher("ABC");

    var crypt = Cypher("FooBar Crypt me!", 42, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    var decrypt = Cypher(crypt, alphabet.Length - 42);
}
```

In addition, Decrypt is simply a crypt where the key is `alphabet.Length - key`:

```
string Decypher(string word, int key, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    => Cypher(word, alphabet.Length - key, comparisonType);
```